# Uploading from android app, database entry inserts, but image is not inserted

Tags: php, android, mysql, image-uploading

I am trying to implement a user upload in my android application. For some reason, the code below seems to not be able to upload images, i.e, the database entry is done, but the image is not found in the folder. Can someone help with this? I followed this tutorial : https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/
The path is correct as I can see the path being used in the database entry done.

```
<?php 

require_once 'dbDetails.php';

$upload_path = 'usr_upload/';

$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

$upload_url = 'http://'.$server_ip.'/wallpaper/games/'.$upload_path;

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_FILES['image']['name'])){
        $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('unable to connect to database ');
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $fileinfo = pathinfo($_FILES['image']['name']);

        $extension = $fileinfo['extension'];

        $file_url = $upload_url . getFileName() . '.'.$extension; 

        $file_path = $upload_path. getFileName(). '.'.$extension; 

        try{

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $file_path);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO images (url, name) VALUES ('$file_url','$name')";
            if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
                $response['error'] = false; 
                $response['url'] = $file_url; 
                $response['name'] = $name; 
            }

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $response['error'] = false; 
            $response['message'] = $e->getMessage(); 
        }
        mysqli_close($con);

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Please choose a file';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}

function getFileName(){
    $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die('Unable to connect');
    $sql = "SELECT max(id) as id FROM images";
    $result = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con,$sql));
    mysqli_close($con);
    if($result['id']==null){
        return 1; 
    }else{
        return ++$result['id'];
    }
}
```

The error log created is:

> PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpSv15lI' to 'usr_upload/3.jpg' in DOMAINNAME.COM/wallpaper/games/usr_upload/upload.php on line 28

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp] you can use this code to upload the file.

Comment: this is more than likely because the folder can't be written to. The HTML form is unknown, so make sure that isn't failing also.

Comment: @HK007 The link you gave says 404 not found

Comment: @Fred-ii- The permissions on my server are set for all access. And the code doesn't work on localhost either. I'm calling this php code from my android application on a button click, I get the message 'File Upload Complete' on my phone but its not being shown in the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself, turns out the link I specified in the php file was wrong.